# Saving a canvas in a format other than image formats

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have created a canvas using java script.I have used EditText also.I want to save the canvas in a format so that i can again open it and see the edit text.Now i am saving it as image png file.But once i save it edittext is nt getting saved only image is getting saved.Is it possible to save canvas in some other format than image?? Please give me your valuable solutions as soon as possible

Comment: This is not clear.... maybe a screen shot -- no idea what you mean by EditText.

Comment: I meant a textarea which once created can be edited again clicking on the text.how can i implement that.Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Still not clear -- textarea and canvas are two separate things -- how and why are they combined here.  This leads me to believe that I don't know what you are talking about.  Post a screen shot or example code.

Comment: I have a canvas and am adding a DIV on it because i want it to be lika a notebook where user can write text and draw.By making Contenteditable property of DIV true i am making div editable.But once i save the canvas into image format the drawings appear bt the text which i wrote into the div is not getting saved in that image